# How to call a PostgreSQL function that does not wait for completion?

Tags: python

I have a data pipeline that after wrangling data it creates a new table in a PostgreSQL database and inserts data into such table. I also have a PostgreSQL function that I want to call after the process. The postgres function is pretty heavy and can take up to 10 minutes to finish. I want Python to call the postgres function but do not wait until resolves.

I am using psycogpg2-binary but it waits until the postgres function is completed:

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(user=configs.USERNAME,
                            password=configs.PASSWORD,
                            host=configs.HOST,
                            port=configs.PORT,
                            dbname=configs.DATABASE)
    
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM wrangler_func('new_data')")
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your problem, what can be done to call a PostgreSQL function without waiting for it to finish, we can use the asyncio module with the asyncpg library, which will allow you to execute the PostgreSQL function asynchronously.

Now the first thing is to install the asyncpg library, if you don't have it installed:

```py
pip install asyncpg
```

Then we import the necessary modules

```py
import asyncio
import asyncpg
```

Now we create the asynchronous function that will connect to our database and execute the PostgreSQL function:

```py
async def call_postgres_function():
     # Replace with your own connection data
     conn = await asyncpg.connect(user='your_user', password='your_password', database='your_database', host='your_host', port='your_port')
    
     # Call the PostgreSQL function (replace 'your_function' with the name of your function)
     await conn.execute('SELECT your_function();')
    
     # close the connection
     await conn.close()
```

Finally we are going to execute the asynchronous function

```py
# Execute the asynchronous function
asyncio.create_task(call_postgres_function())

# Now your program will continue without waiting for the PostgreSQL function to finish.
```

Greetings!

Comment: That unfortunately does not work as there is nothing wait for. I want literally to cancel the "await" so the whole application finishes.